# NotFoundError running TensorFlow XLA example (libdevice.compute_35.10.bc)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running the [tutorial example for XLA](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/experimental/xla/jit) using a TensorFlow compiled from source.  Running `python mnist_softmax_xla.py` results in the following error:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0)
I tensorflow/core/platform/default/cuda_libdevice_path.cc:35] TEST_SRCDIR environment variable not set: using local_config_cuda/cuda under this executable's runfiles directory as the CUDA root.
I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform CUDA present with 1 visible devices
I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform Host present with 4 visible devices
I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:180] XLA service executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:187]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform CUDA present with 1 visible devices
I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:58] platform Host present with 4 visible devices
I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:180] XLA service executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:187]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla K80, Compute Capability 3.7
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Not found: ./libdevice.compute_35.10.bc not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/software/envs/xla/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/mnt/software/envs/xla/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/mnt/software/envs/xla/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: ./libdevice.compute_35.10.bc not found
         [[Node: cluster_0/_0/_1 = _XlaLaunch[Targs=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], Tconstants=[DT_INT32], Tresults=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], function=cluster_0[_XlaCompiledKernel=true, _XlaNumConstantArgs=1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](Shape_2, _recv_Placeholder_0/_3, _recv_Placeholder_1_0/_1, Variable_1, Variable)]]
```

I have CUDA 8 installed with cuDNN 5.1.  The file `libdevice.compute_35.10.bc` does exist on the machine:

```
$ find /usr/local/cuda/ -type f | grep libdevice.compute_35.10.bc
/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice/libdevice.compute_35.10.bc
```

My hunch is that this has something to do with the message `TEST_SRCDIR environment variable not set: using local_config_cuda/cuda under this executable's runfiles directory as the CUDA root.`, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Comment: double check your LD_LIBRARY_CONFIG env variable, otherwise looks like a bug to me. Fill one issue to the github repo.

Comment: Do you mean `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?  I'm skeptical that that's the problem, as most CUDA shared libraries in /usr/local/cuda already appear in the output of `sudo ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep cuda`.

Comment: Hi, I'm an XLA developer at Google.  I actually found your question after encountering it myself and googling the error.  :)

I'm not sure yet what's wrong, but I doubt LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the solution, because libdevice is not a shared library.

I'll update this question once I figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is this log message:

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/default/cuda_libdevice_path.cc:35] TEST_SRCDIR environment variable not set: using local_config_cuda/cuda under this executable's runfiles directory as the CUDA root.
```

(I only noticed it in the logs later; I actually found that file by digging around in the sources and only then noticed the message in the logs.)

For reasons that I do not currently understand, XLA does not look in /usr/local/cuda (or whatever directory you gave when you ran `./configure`) for libdevice.  Per cuda_libdevice_path.cc [1], it's looking for a symlink that was created specifically to point it to libdevice.

I'm going to loop in the person who wrote this code to figure out what it's supposed to be doing.  In the meantime, I was able to work around it myself as follows:

```
$ mkdir local_config_cuda
$ ln -s /usr/local/cuda local_config_cuda/cuda
$ TEST_SRCDIR=$(pwd) python my_program.py
```

The important thing is to set `TEST_SRCDIR` to the parent of the local_config_cuda directory.

Sorry for the trouble, and sorry I don't have a less-hacky answer for you right now.

[1] https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e1f44d8/tensorflow/core/platform/cuda_libdevice_path.cc#L23 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1084748efa3234c7daa824718aeb7df7b9252def/tensorflow/core/platform/default/cuda_libdevice_path.cc#L27

Comment: Using your fix, then adding /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 to the library path (via ld.so.conf.d/), I got the XLA example code to run.  Thanks!  Could the XLA team update their tutorial with these steps?

Comment: We're on it.  I don't think the TEST_SRCDIR bit should be necessary.  And there may be a way to do the LD_LIBRARY_PATH bit ourselves as well.  Like, you *told* us where your CUDA was when you ran configure.  :)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/7079 should be able to fix this. Thanks for the bug report!